# Python Multiple inheritance

Tags: python

I have 3 classes A,B and D as given below

```
class A(object):
    def test(self):
        print "called A"

class B(object):
    def test(self):
        print "called B"

class D(A,B):
    def test(self):
        super(A,self).test()

inst_d=D()
inst_d.test()

----------------------------------------
Output:
  called B
```

Question: In `D.test()`, I am calling `super(A,self).test()`. Why is only `B.test()` called even though the method `A.test()` also exists?

Comment: The way Python's super works is somewhat non-obvious. A great practical guide on using it correctly is this one: http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Answer (score 6):

Because you've told it not to. In `D.test` you've told it to call the test method of the *parent* of A - that's what `super` does.

Normally you want to use the current class name in the `super` call.

Comment: Also, the other classes need to also call `super()` to get the next class in the MRO.

Comment: And "normally" might as well be "pretty much always"; a hypothetical use case for skipping to a random place in the method resolution order would probably be rather exotic.

Comment: The answer is a little unclear - `B` is not the parent of `A`, so it isn't obvious why `B.test()` is called.

Comment: Thanks Daniel ,in this case mro will start from parent of A not from class A got it.

Comment: @Anoop: Exactly. The first parameter to `super()` indicates where the *currently executing* method is in the MRO that built by starting at the type of the second parameter. Then the method called through the resulting proxy will be the next one in the MRO after the current one.

Answer (score 0):

`super(A,self).test()` means : call the `test` method of the object after A in `self`'s method resolution order (mro) .

using `D.__mro__` you see the the method resolution order is:

```
<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <type 'object'>
```

So `test` of `B` is called.

In Python 3 you only have to type `super().test()` and it does what you want. In Python 2 you need to type : `super(D,self).test()`

Answer (score 0):

Usually the super is called with the current class name and you let the MRO of python to take care which parent class it should call according to the algorithm it follows. So your code will look like this, for the behavior you intend.

```
class D(A,B):
    def test(self):
        super(D,self).test()
```

Note `super(D,self).test()`